# need to hold on keyboard key in order to type

Tags: keyboard

I was using MINT and suddenly keyboard stopped working properly, And if I want to type any thing then I have to hold on each key for 1-5 second.
Now I have UBUNTU 14.04 (64-bit on HP-dv6) installed and I am still having the same problem.
Please note that:

1. Everything is updated.
2. Keyboard is working while on Grub/BIOS perfectly.
3. During Ubuntu installation when I tested the keyboard it was working too.
4. Sticky keys, Slow keys, Bounce keys are all switched off.
5. I’m using a fresh Ubuntu install and I **don't** have windows (dualboot).

Edit: repeat keys are off, if I enable it the keyboard goes crazy and keeps typing pressed letters

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: When you press NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock, do they lag?

Comment: Yes they lag too, I dont think its a lag because if i press the key normally then the letter wont be written event if I wait for it. I need to hold on the key to be written

Comment: Check the settings/universal access/typing and ensure all are turned off.  One of them adjusts the letter acceptance delay.

Comment: Yes all are off

Comment: @ubfan1 hey brother, you're life saver, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having a problem with a keyboard that doesn't get reset properly during BIOS initialisation (after a BIOS upgrade?) or *the keyboard is going bad*.

Do the following:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `atkbd.reset` after `quiet splash`
2. Save the file
3. Run `update-grub`
4. Reboot

The `atkbd.reset` [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) will reset your hardware keyboard controller through software.

If you get `syslog` messages that contain `keyboard reset failed`, and you did not perform any BIOS upgrade, please remove the keyboard (if a laptop: download the service manual first), clean the connectors and the keys and re-insert it.  If that doesn't help, replace it altogether as this is a sign of imminent hardware failure...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)